# How to easily create and deform multiline wires?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestion you could provide for this topic:
I am modeling a robot with servomotors, and all the servomotors have 3-line wires (a red line for input voltage, a black line for the ground, and a yellow line for control pulses), as shown in the picture (the black boxes are the servomotors):

[image: servomotors image]

Currently, I am modeling each wire separately as a bezier curve. But it is time consuming to route the wires separately through the body of the robot because I have to do it 3 times (for each different wire) and I have to make them fit together through the route as if they were attached together.

My question is: How can I create a 3 wire structure like that (3 wires of a different color) and move and edit them as if it was a single wire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try the *Hook* solution? Hook the curve vertices to an empty:

[image]

Now another solution that doesn't fit your needs as your curve have different colors:

Create your curve. Create its profile (create a *Curve > Circle*, duplicate it in *Edit* mode). Select the curve, in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Geometry > Bevel*, click on *Object* and choose the 3 circle curve as *Object*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Moonboots. I have already tried that, but I can´t select a different color for each wire (unless I convert to mesh the wires, but in that case I loose the bezier advantage).

Comment: oh ok sorry, maybe hooks then?